# Query user_field_data in Drupal

Tags: authentication-authorization, external-scripts

I need to query the user_field_data table to see if a user exists. Through a query string, I pass to a php script that is on the server username and password in clear text. This script connects to the database, and then it should encrypt the password to do the query, but it doesn't work. Anyone knows why don't work? thank you

````
<?php
        $nome_ut = $_GET['nome'];

        use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
        use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
        // Boot Drupal.
        $autoloader = require __DIR__ . '/autoload.php';
        
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($request, $autoloader, 'prod', FALSE);
        $kernel->boot();
        
        // Get password hasher service.
        $password_hasher = $kernel->getContainer()->get('password');
        
        // Hash password.
        if (isset($_GET['pwd']) && !empty($_GET['pwd'])) {
            $pass_ut =  $password_hasher->hash($_GET['pwd']);
        }
        else {
            die('password non impostata');
        }

        print("pass_ut : ".$pass_ut."<BR>");
        $loggato = false;
        $tabella = "users_field_data";
        print ("nome_ut:". $nome_ut."<BR>");
        // dati del Database
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "root";
        $dbname = "prova";
        if ($nome_ut == "")
    {
        die ("Inserire Nome Utente!<BR>");
    }
        // Creo la connessione
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Verifico connessione 
        if ($conn->connect_error)
            {
                die("Connessione fallita: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }
        else {
            print("Connessione eseguita!<BR>");
                //verifico l'esistenza di nome utente e password
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users_field_data WHERE name = '$nome_ut' AND pass = '$pass_ut'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)        {
            print ("accesso eseguito!<BR>");
            $numero_righe = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            print ("numero righe =". $numero_righe."<BR>");
            $loggato = true;
        }
        else
        {
            print ("accesso negato<BR>");
        } 
                }
    ?>```
````

Answer (score 1):

Drupal core already has code to verify the login credentials are correct. Since Drupal implements the necessary Symfony services, it's not even necessary to directly access the database.

I use the [`UserLoginForm`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Form%21UserLoginForm.php/class/UserLoginForm/8.9.x) class as guideline to write code to verify the login credentials. I will leave out the part for bootstrapping Drupal.

```php
use Drupal\user\UserAuthInterface;
use Drupal\user\UserInterface;
use Drupal\user\UserStorageInterface;

$user_auth = \Drupal::service('user.auth');
$user_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user');

$accounts = $user_storage->loadByProperties(['name' => $username, 'status' => 1]);
$account = reset($accounts);

if ($account) {
  if ($user_auth->authenticate($username, $password)) {
    // The credentials are correct.
}
```

I first checked there is an account with the given username, as [`$user_auth->authenticate()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21UserAuth.php/function/UserAuth%3A%3Aauthenticate/8.9.x) doesn't check the account hasn't been blocked. Without that part, the code is even shorter.

```php
use Drupal\user\UserAuthInterface;

$user_auth = \Drupal::service('user.auth');

if ($user_auth->authenticate($username, $password)) {
  // The credentials are correct.
}
```

`$user_auth->authenticate()` returns the user ID, which is helpful if you need to load the User entity that matches the login credentials.